# Facebook ads comments

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I want to obtain the comments on ads asociated to a fanpage. I already get all the comments associated to posts, but I want the ones on ads that are not linked to a post. Is this possible? If yes, how can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean comments that are not linked to a post? Can you provide an example?

Comment: for ads, not promoted posts.

Comment: If you have the ad ID, then you can try getting `effective_object_story_id ` from the ad creative and try making a GET request to `{effective_object_story_id}/comments`. Check the doc here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative/